# Showing value data from dropdown in html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dom

I created a script which get from my database the states and price of shipping by number of products.

So...I have 2 dropdown, one for quantity and the second one for state.

This is my main php file: http://pastebin.com/U6dncsZ6 
This is the second php file (for database connect) - findcity.php : http://pastebin.com/AuEXrnpD

As you see, in my second php file I have this line:

```
<option value=<?=$row['price']?>><?=$row['title']?></option>
```

I want to display the shipping price from the database ($row['price'] on the page.
I specify that using "Inspect element" in my browser I can see the prices added as value for the states, like:

```
<option value="48.11">State</option>
```

Please help :(

**Le: As I stated in a comment, I finally found that like here it's working: jsfiddle.net/Dkn4n/1/
But for some reasons, it's not detected but it's not working in my page, maybe because the value is not set in html, I can't see the values in source, only in "Inspect element". The value is set as I specified above, with $row['price']**

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is...

Comment: so what seems to be the problem here, officer?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is... It seems like you should also echo the elements instead of just writing $row['...'] though.

Comment: I hope you won't be using those price values for your actual shipping calculation. A malicious user can trivially change those to be 0 and get free shipping.

Comment: @MarcB Of course not, I will all those data from database but are used there only for the calculator, not the real shop :) Just a simple html page for simulate the shipping prices. Thank you for advice.

Comment: Ok guys, I finally made it working this way: http://jsfiddle.net/Dkn4n/1/                                                 the problem is...in the above example is working, but in my live page not, because I'm using <option value=<?=$row['price']?>><?=$row['title']?></option> and can't get the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to "Chase"s Answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#provincia").change(function(){
   $("#selectedprice").html(this.value);
   //<div id=selectedprice></div> should show  your value
 });
});
```

and expanding it:

at this line:
    document.getElementById('provinciadiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;

do

```
    $("#provincia").change(function(){
       $("#selectedprice").html(this.value);
       //<div id=selectedprice></div> should show  your value
     });
```

again!
Because the "change" binding is gone once you replace the part...

Comment: YOU ROCK !!!! Everything it's working now ! Amazing ! Thank you so much for your help. I needed to add that code to document.getElementById('provinciadiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;

Answer (score 2):

Your select statement looks like this on the page:

```
<select id="provincia">
    <option value="10.00">CA</option>
    <option value="20.00">NY</option>
</select>
```

So using javascript/jQuery you can do the following to get the value of the selected option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#provincia").change(function(){
   alert(this.value);
   //do stuff here to set the value where you want it.
 });
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dkn4n/

Comment: That's what I want, but I would like to display the result in a div, not alert. That's the thing I can't get it work :(

Comment: I'll update the fiddle and code here shortly with what you're looking for. I'm currently at work, but I'll find some time to help ya out =) ---EDIT: looks like you found the solution you wanted there. The .html() function should work nicely for you. Sorry I wasn't around to answer.

Comment: everything is ok now and working nicely thanks to you. Thank you for all your help.